# How to add text and image into one link and display it over that image on site?

Tags: html, css

Can you give me advice how to display text over image. Text is variable i can't workaround it with photoshop ? Image is responsive image is centered and in link bakcground is repeated. Width and height is ok.  Thank you very much.

How it should looks like:

[image: image_with_text]

How it looks now:

[image: image_without_text]

Image repeated on X:

[image: image_repeated]

CSS:

```
a.elipsis{
    background: url('showmore-bg.png') repeat-x;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a style="display:block; width 100%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center" class="elipsis" href="#">
  show more <!-- text that should be over image -->
  <img style="position: relative;" class="cond-arr" src="/css/show_more.png" alt="show_more" />
</a>
```

Comment: What you need is to resize the text according to the background image, right?

Comment: I don't want to resize, I want to display that b tag with text over image.

Comment: Well, try removing the i tag... it is deprecated on CSS, so you shouldn't be using it, in the first place... same with b tag.

Comment: OK i use strong insted of b. I don't think it solve my problem.

Comment: Could the text just be added to the button image or does it have to be seperate?

Comment: @lthreed He already said it is variable text.

Comment: It's in variable because i use function to translate text show more to different languages.

Comment: I don't know why text is not displayed. It should be above the background, no matter which z-index level. Perhaps another CSS selector is making the trouble?

Comment: Yes now when i added that semicolon after text-align: center it display above that image with repeated background i need to display it in same line if possible as on picture I added

Comment: @Sakhal Turkaystan CSS selector for link is used in css as a.elipsis so i think it's not a problem

Comment: No JSFiddle provided?

Comment: But is that one the only selector affecting anchors in all the scope of the page?

Comment: Yes, that one is for all link but it only removes underline: `a:link,a:visited,a:hover,a:active{
    text-decoration:  none !important;
}`

Comment: Please provide JSFiddle, link to web page with full content or post your full code so we can see where is the problem.

Comment: jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NcxhL/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/digiman07/VATyH/

Comment: @Malcolm Where is that background repeat ? Why div's instead of my structure ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much you can change your approach but you could have a div in which you would have your anchor and in CSS you could set the background for that div to be your image and set the dimensions of the div to bew exact the same size as your image.

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/jHmP7/1/

```
<div class="imageContainer">
    <a style="display:block; width 100%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center" class="elipsis" href="#">Some Text</a>
</div>


.imageContainer {
       width:200px; 
       height:100px; 
       background-image: url(your image);
 }
```

Comment: jsfiddle : jsfiddle.net/NcxhL

Answer (score 0):

You just just put your image as a background of your link and wrap it in a div.
You give your link a fixed size, and your wrapper will handle the responsive part.

It would give something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <a style="display:block; text-align: center" class="elipsis" href="#">
    show more <!-- text that should be over image -->
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a.elipsis{
    background: url('show_more.png') no-repeat;
    width: xxx; /* width of your image */
    height: xxx; /* height of your image */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

div.wrapper {
    background: url('showmore-bg.png') repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In case it doesn't work please provide a jsfiddle so we can work on it.

Comment: Where is my image bro i need static image inside ? I mean <img because in jquery function i replace background of that image for different pages I need to get to attribute src

Comment: Ok I didn't know that, however in jQuery you can replace as easily the background-image of your link. Or you can even prepare several CSS classes with your different images and switch the classes in jQuery. It seems the cleaner solution to me. Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NcxhL/2/ I suppose it's what you want. Maybe you can update your fiddle with your jQuery then we can see how to handle your image switch.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best solution, but it is the only solution I can get with your current markup. I'll give absolute positioning to text and relative to link. After that, with jQuery I will calculate position of text, based on width of link and width of whole text.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function center(){
        var link_w = $('#link').width();
        var text_w = $('#text').width();
        $('#text').css('left', link_w/2-text_w/2+'px');
    };
    center();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        center();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NcxhL/1/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following will do what you are looking for.

CSS

```
.elipsis {
    margin: 0px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(showmore_bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.elipsis .showmore{
    background-image: url(showmore.png);
    height: 32px;
    width: 295px;
    bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<a class="elipsis" href="#">
<p class="showmore">show more</p>
</a>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/digiman07/6U7yT/)